# The space of $L^2$ integrable holomorphic functions on the unit disk

Tags: analysis

I am to show that the space of $L^2$-integrable, holomorphic functions on the unit disk is a Hilbert space.

I am very unfamiliar with this material, so please forgive any confusion coming through in my following "explanation".

I have finally understood the proof that $L^2$ is complete, and given the inner product, $\langle f|g \rangle= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bar{f}(z)g(z)dz$, this makes it a Hilbert space.

My confusion is how to adapt this to specifically the holomorphic functions on the unit disk. Does it change the terms of integration? What other changes do I need to make? Any extra explanation would be of great help. TIA.

Comment: what you have to show is for a Cauchy-sequence (w.r.t. the $L^2$-norm) $f_n$ on $\mathbb D$ of holomorphic function which are $L^2$-integrable which is cauchy that there exists a limit function $f$ on $\mathbb D$ which again is $L^2$-integrable and holomorphic with $\Vert f_n - f \Vert_{L^2} \to 0$.

As far as I unterstand you can use completeness of the space $L^2 (\mathbb D)$ so you know that there is a limit function $f \in L^2 ( \mathbb D)$. What remains to show is that this $f$ is holomorphic.

Comment: @Targon Okay, so to show that this $f$ is holomorphic, what would I do? The rest of your explanation helps a lot, but this last step I am still struggling with

Comment: I posted an answer dealing with this. Also, I see now that the scalar product in your question is slightly off, you have to integrate over $\mathbb D$ instead of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call this space $L^2_h := \big\{ f : \mathbb D \to \mathbb C : f \text{ is holomorphic and } f \in L^2 (\mathbb D ) \big\}$. For $a \in \mathbb D$ you can show $\vert f(a) \vert \leq C \cdot \Vert f \Vert_{L^2}$ for some constant $C>0$ which is locally independent of $a$.
For this calculation see [this script, prop. 5.6.1](https://www.math.uni-tuebingen.de/user/deitmar/LEHRE/alt/2019/RS/RS.pdf). It is in German but you'll just have to see the calculation.
Therefore, if you have a Cauchy-sequence $(f_n)_n$ in $L^2_h$, it follows that this sequence converges locally uniformly to some function $f \colon \mathbb D \to \mathbb C$. This implies, that $f$ is holomorphic.

Comment: What do you mean by "**locally** independent of $a$"? We already are on the unit disk, which is compact. I think that "locally" is not necessary here.

Comment: actually we are looking at the open unit disk so I think it is necessary although I don't have a good example for that

Comment: and what I mean by that is for every $a \in \mathbb D$ there are $\varepsilon >0$ and $C>0$ such that for every $a' \in B_\varepsilon (a)$ we have $\vert f(a') \vert < C \cdot \Vert f \Vert_{L^2}$.

Comment: Oh, it's the open disk. Then you are right, "locally" is necessary. Thank you for the explanation